# Apache Camel : File to BeanIO and merge beanIO objects based on id

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, aggregator

I have the usecase to read employee, address and contact files in parallel and convert that to beanIO object and merge the beanIO object to produce the complete employeeDetails object.

Emp File:

```
1 Foo Engineer
2 Bar AssistantEngineer
```

Emp Contact File:

```
1 8912345678  foo@org.com
2 7812345678    bar@org.com
```

Emp Address File:

```
 1 city1 1234
 2 city2 2345
```

Expected output in a EmployeeDetailsBeanIODataFormat object in Exchange:

```
1 Foo Engineer foo@org.com city1 1234
2 Bar AssistantEngineer bar@org.com city2 2345
```

I have the following routes

```
from("file://C:/cameltest/employee.txt").to("seda:beanIO");
from("file://C:/cameltest/employeeContact.txt").to("seda:beanIOContact");
from("file://C:/cameltest/employeeAddress.txt").to("seda:beanIOAddress");
```

Each file is converted to beanio object

```
BeanIODataFormat empFormat = new BeanIODataFormat("beanIO.xml","emp");
BeanIODataFormat empContactFormat = new BeanIODataFormat("beanIO.xml", "empContact");
BeanIODataFormat empAddressFormat = new BeanIODataFormat("beanIO.xml", "empAddress");

from("seda:beanIO").unmarshal(empFormat).log("body - ${body}");        
from("seda:beanIOContact").unmarshal(empContactFormat).log("Contact body ${body}");
from("seda:beanIO").unmarshal(empAddressFormat).log("Address body - ${body}");
```

The output logs the bean objects correctly.

Now I need to merge the objects to form EmployeeDetails object. Can someone let me know how to do this? I have read and it seems like Aggregators can be used to do this job, but not sure with the approach.

Any idea on this with sample will be helpful.
Suggestions are welcome, is it advisable to merge the files first based on employee id and create an object out of it? I dont want to write the merged file into disk in this case as IO will cost the performance.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a splitter to split each message after the unmarshalling

```
from("seda:beanIO").unmarshal(empFormat).split(body()).to("seda:aggregate");
from("seda:beanIOContact").unmarshal(empContactFormat).split(body()).to("seda:aggregate");
from("seda:beanIOAddress").unmarshal(empAddressFormat).split(body()).to("seda:aggregate");
```

And then here is how an aggregator could look like. 
The details object is stored as a header in the olddExchange.
The most important parameters are the following

1. correlationExpression: simple("${body.id}") Correlate all the messages with the same id(1 or 2)
2. completionSize=3.  One for each file.

---

```
from("seda:aggregate").aggregate(simple("${body.id}"), (oldExchange,newExchange) -> {
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            EmployeeDetails details = buildDetails(new EmployeeDetails(), newExchange);
            newExchange.getIn().setHeader("details", details);
            return newExchange;
        }
        EmployeeDetails details = oldExchange.getIn().getHeader("details", EmployeeDetails.class);
        buildDetails(details, newExchange);
        oldExchange.getIn().setHeader("details", details);
        return oldExchange;
    }).completionSize(3).log("Details - ${header.details}")
```

And

```
private EmployeeDetails buildDetails(EmployeeDetails details, Exchange newExchange) {
        Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        if (newBody instanceof Employee) {
            details.setId(((Employee) newBody).getId());
            details.setName(((Employee) newBody).getName());
            details.setJob(((Employee) newBody).getJob());
        } else if (newBody instanceof EmployeeContact) {
            details.setEmail(((EmployeeContact) newBody).getEmail());
        } else if (newBody instanceof EmployeeAddress) {
            details.setCity(((EmployeeAddress) newBody).getCity());
            details.setCode(((EmployeeAddress) newBody).getCode());
        }
        return details;
    }
```

Then the outcome would be 2 details objects

```
Details - EmployeeDetails(id=1, name=Foo, job=Engineer, email=foo@org.com, city=city1, code=1234)
Details - EmployeeDetails(id=2, name=Bar, job=AssistantEnginee, email=bar@org.com, city=city2, code=2345)
```

Comment: it works fine, however EmployeeDetails are printed one by one. But I would need the final output an EmployeeDetails[] in Exchange body so I can pass it on next route to process the final list and convert it to Avro format.  Does it need aggregation again?  ......completionSize(3).to("seda"formList") ? would something like this  work or is there anyother option to group all the messages.

Comment: You could aggregate again(although this is a different question) .setBody(header("details")).aggregate(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()).constant(true).complet‌​ionSize(2) where 2 is the number of ids

Comment: @Itsallas, Tried GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy and getting error in grouping the exchanges, created a new question for the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870073/apache-camel-groupedexchangeaggregationstrategy-groups-defaultexchange-instead